# IK Bone Constrain - Foot is weirdly rotated

Tags: armature, bones

I am trying to create bones for my armature follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBYb1YmaOMY&t=185s). However, when I apply the IK bone constraint, my foot rotates weirdly. It goes from this in Edit Mode:

[image]

To this in Pose Mode:

[image]

I have set all my bones Roll to be the same at 0 degrees but that doesn't fix my problem. I have also tried adjusting the Pole Angle as well. What ends up happening is that if I fix the foot rotation by either adjust UpperLeg.R Roll or Pole Angle, my knee no longer bends correctly. The other 2 parts of the legs roll do nothing to help. I tried looking at a bunch of other similar questions, but I don't know I can't seem to quite get it right.

Pasteall: https://pasteall.org/blend/b42573b8587e469d911befa446103034

Blend-Exchange: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you need to bend the knee a bit forward in *Edit* mode, so that it knows in what direction it is supposed to bend, and then in *Pose* mode change the IK *Pole Angle* (to something around -75°):

[image]

Comment: I tried that and the knee bends towards an angle still. Am I doing something particularly wrong?

Comment: your upper leg and lower leg are not aligned, so it makes it bend a bit awkwardly, maybe align them?

Comment: Yep, that ended up being it. It is always something I assumed didn't matter, appreciate it.